# Openserver curl?

Tags: curl, openserver

Хочу установить пиджак https://github.com/yiisoft/jquery-pjax
Для этого он предлагает использовать курл

```
pjax can be downloaded directly into your app's public directory - just be sure you've loaded jQuery first.

curl -LO https://raw.github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/master/jquery.pjax.js

WARNING Do not hotlink the raw script url. GitHub is not a CDN.
```

я использую openserver 5.2.2.
в консоли прописываю и получаю

```
curl -LO https://raw.github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/master/jquery.pjax.js
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:20 --:--:-- 0curl: (7) Failed connect to github.com:443; No error
```

в чем может быть проблема?

в пхпинфо курл виден

```
curl
cURL support enabled
cURL Information 7.39.0
```

Comment: А попробуйте скачать curl-ом что-нибудь по протоколу HTTP (не HTTPS). Проблема продолжит воспроизводиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема, скорее всего, в том, что вы находитесь за прокси-сервером.

Укажите прокси-сервер с помощью переменных окружения

```
http_proxy
https_proxy
```

и попробуйте скачать файл.

Например:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.lan:3128/ https_proxy=http://proxy.lan:3128 curl http://...
```

Comment: Я вроде пытался. та же трабла была с композером. можете развернуто написать как

Comment: @des1roer: написал пример. Обратите внимание, что всё в одну строку

Comment: это критично? ...

Comment: в принципе раньше пн проверить не смогу. а вы понимаете что консоль у openserver и linux различна?

Comment: @des1roer: в данном случае все вариаты curl'а это должны понимать

Comment: @des1roer: Я с OpenServer (если вы SCO OpenServer имеете ввиду) работаю с 5.0.3 (то есть больше 15 лет), и там это всё будет прекрасно работать, а если вы имеете в виду OpenServer, который http://open-server.ru/, то опять же никаких проблем

Comment: да я про локальную среду разработки